# Notify icon messages won't impress MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx

Tags: winapi, notifyicon

I am using `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx()` for my message loop, and `Shell_NotifyIcon` to create tray icons.

Here's the deal: Whenever the tray icon sends messages to it's owner window, the window won't receive the messages right away, instead they will get queued until any other type of message arrives (`WM_MOUSEMOVE`, for example).

Seems like the messages from the tray icon won't get `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx()` out of the wait state for some reason, although I am calling `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx()` with `QS_ALLEVENTS` wake mask.

I use `WM_USER` + ... for `NOTIFYICONDATA::uCallbackMessage`, and I also tried to use a "concrete" value (`WM_MOVE`,...) instead. Didn't help.

Did anyone ever faced this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't you tried with QS_ALLINPUT instead of QS_ALLEVENTS?